# How to add a satellite view in android studio?

Tags: android, view, satellite

My map is working fine.However, i want to add a satellite view along with my normal view? How can i achieve that?

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {


private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;


    LatLng location = new LatLng(x,y);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ReduitBusStop).title("you are here!"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));
```

Comment: Try adding `mMap.setMapType(mMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);`

Comment: Use this - mMap.setMapType(mMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

Comment: @Lal: its allowing only satellite view now. i want both of them to displayed one at a time

Comment: @Shane: its allowing only satellite view now. i want both of them to displayed one at a time

Comment: @joey see the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27178343/3168859)

Answer (score 32):

Try with setting the type of map tiles as below

```
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the below function to set the satellite view
`setMapType(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);`