# Google Map Android API mapTypeControl options over map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Is there an option available out of the box to display map type controls in google map android API like
[image]

as there is an option in javascript API where while initializing map by passing this `mapTypeControl: true,` map type controls are displayed automatically like this[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has provided api to set MapType runtime programatically but i guess there is no API to invoke dialog like interface for user to choose map type as shown in image. To solve this devs have been constructing their own dialog with for eg radio buttons to choose map type and on user selection they are changing the property to desired one.

```
API - map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
```

You can check similar implementation [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064857/making-an-android-map-menu-to-change-map-type)

Comment: thanks for the reply, I knew how to change type pragmatically but was wondering if there were some out of the box implementation of it, which I couldn't find so I asked to confirm.